# How to add AO image as node in shading view?

Tags: node-editor

I have this hair texture that comes with 6 images, when I open the file I see this:

[image]

I do have node wranger enabled, however when I import these images using "ctrl shift T" I do not get the **AO** node, how do I get it? I also didn't get the "Base Color" node either in the beginning, but then I renamed the image from `04-basecolor` to `04-color` and it worked.

I don't know why `04-color` works in the example file, I guess I should rename the `ao` image as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of these are the same 'Image texture' node that have been renamed for organisation. The names in the orange section don't change the function of the node but are used to keep things organised and help you plug them into the right inputs of your shader.

While there is a dedicated AO node that you can find using Shift+A > Input > Ambient Occlusion, it is used to generate ambient occlusion automatically from the geometry (only works in cycles) but since you already have an AO texture you won't need to use that here.

Instead the common practice for using an AO texture with your Albedo (Base Color) is to mix them using a 'Mix Color' node set to an Overlay blending mode and dialling in the Factor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can correct me here.. 'Overlay' seems an odd mix-mode to use, here, since it will brighten in light areas as well as darkening in  ambiently occluded areas. I suppose it's all non-physical, anyway...